# RXJS Tap function

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have this code can you please explain what does TAP function doing here?

```
 resend(id: number): void {
        this.orderService.resend(id).pipe(tap(() => { // TAP ()
            this.snackBarService.successMessage('table.resend_success_message');
          },
          error => this.snackBarService.errorMessage(),
        )).subscribe(() => {
          return this.getList(this.params);
        });
      }
```

Comment: The function under "tap" is executed each time the observable is "executed" without change the response. Generally is used to "log" the response (sometimes is used to store an intermed value response). In this case, it execute a method of "snackBarService" -possible make a "log" or show a message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment of @Eliseo is correct but I will try to give you an example.
In your case it's the same thing as doing this:

```js
this.orderService.resend(id).subscribe(() => {
    this.snackBarService.successMessage('table.resend_success_message');
    return this.getList(this.params);
});
```

But this approach has some downside. If you want to subscribe to `this.orderService.resend(id)` from many places, you alway need to call  `this.snackBarService.successMessage`. This is bad practice because we don't want to rewrite the same code multiple timse.

So a solution would be this:

```js
resend$(id):Observable<any> { // this will return your list
    return this.orderService.resend(id).pipe(
        tap(() => this.snackBarService.successMessage('table.resend_success_message')),
        map(() => this.getList(this.params))
    );
});

test(){
    this.resend$(1).subscribe(
        myList => {
            // here you will have the list, no need to successMessage()
        }
    );
}
```

as you can see we could call `this.resend$(1).subscribe()` in multiple places and we don't need to call `this.snackBarService.successMessage` anymore